# GAE-1.7.7's oauth2client/appengine.py:_create_flow(self, request_handler) returns AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an OAuth2 decorator:

```
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS, YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE)
```

... and I sometimes call a function that requires authentication:

```
  playlist_id = youtube_create_playlist(youtube)
```

... so I prepend it with `decorator`:

```
@decorator.oauth_required
def youtube_create_playlist(youtube):
  playlists_insert_response = youtube.playlists().insert(
  ...
```

→ As expected, when stepping into `youtube_create_playlist()`, I go through `oauth2client/appengine.py:oauth_required()`, then `check_oauth()`, then `_create_flow()`, where at line 674 of `appengine.py` 1.7.7 we have:

```
redirect_uri = request_handler.request.relative_url(
          self._callback_path) # Usually /oauth2callback
```

→ But at this step, GAE trips up and throws exception `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'request'`. And indeed I can see in my Variables debugging pane that the `request_handler` object has no attribute 'request'. **Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?** I also created [google-api-python-client issue264](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=264).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok  I think you are missing some understanding on how this decorator will work,

It is intended to be used as a decorator for a web handler (GET/POST handler) in the docs
the example using the Calendar api  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine#Decorators

Shows

```
@decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    # Get the authorized Http object created by the decorator.
    http = decorator.http()
    # Call the service using the authorized Http object.
    request = service.events().list(calendarId='primary')
    response = request.execute(http=http)
    ...
```

You haven't shared all your code, but your `youtube_create_playlist` doesn't look like a 
standard web handler (ok, maybe your not using webapp(2)) and not using class based handlers

The request object needs to be passed in somehow.   In webapp handlers the request is passed in to an instance of the handler when it is requested, and if you set it up this way your method would have access to self.request (and the decorator would too).

If above doesn't make sense I suggest you include more code.

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffman for the clarifications. Indeed I didn't fully understand this decorator. Getting my `http` from the decorator and using it when executing my request did the trick :) But now I'm stuck on another problem that I summed up in [How to properly define GAE's oauth2callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799363/how-to-properly-define-gaes-oauth2callback), may I ask you to have a look?