# How to properly define GAE's oauth2callback?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

The [Using GAE / Decorators](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#Decorators) guide tells me that *"you need to add a specific URL handler to your application to handle the redirection from the authorization server back to your application"*:

```
  def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
       [
         ('/', MainHandler),
         ('/about', AboutHandler),
         (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),
       ],
       debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Currently I am unable to properly set this up. As a result, I get and see the HTTP 302 callback response (while it should be caught by the handler) instead of the response I'm expecting. I have two questions to address that:

1. The `oauth2client/appengine.py` shipping in GAE 1.8.0 has no `callback_path` attribute and no `callback_handler()` method, what are we supposed to do? Directly bind `('/oauth2callback', OAuth2Handler)` instead of `(decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())`?
2. What does that imply for `myapp.yaml`? Is it right to declare a new block like:

   ```
   - url: /oauth2callback
     script: oauth2client/appengine.py
   ```

Thanks for your help! Here is my current code:

---

**myapp.py**

```
class UpdatePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        playlist_id = self.youtube_create_playlist()
        ...

    @decorator.oauth_required
    def youtube_create_playlist(self):
        http = decorator.http()
        request = youtube.playlists().insert(...)
        response = request.execute(http=http)
        return response["id"]

    ...

    update = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                      ('/update', UpdatePage),
                                      ('/oauth2callback', OAuth2Handler)
                                      ],
                                     debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /oauth2callback
  script: oauth2client/appengine.py

- url: /update
  script: myapp.update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library does not ship in App Engine.

The version you should be using is `google-api-python-client-1.1` hosted on the [project download page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-python-client-gae-1.1.zip).

I believe the version you're referring to is the (somewhat old) version of `google-api-python-client` [included in the App Engine SDK](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython%2Flib%2Fgoogle-api-python-client). This is only included to perform simple OAuth 2.0 for `appcfg.py` and is a stable version for performing this simple task. Though it is in the SDK, it is **NOT** in the runtime and not endorsed as a current version of `google-api-python-client` for these reasons.

I'd also like to note that the article you linked explicitly points to [installation instructions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine).

**UPDATE:** As noted there, your WSGI handler should contain the callback from the decorator

```
routes = [
    ('/update', UpdatePage),
    (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),
]
update = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, debug=True)
```

and your `app.yaml` should allow your main handler should either explicitly match the the route in `decorator.callback_path`

```
- url: /oauth2callback
  script: myapp.update
```

or should just route all remaining requests to your WSGI handler

```
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.update
```

(This second approach would likely warrant adding a 404 catch-all to the WSGI handler.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right API to use. However, after installing 1.1, refreshing my project, and ensuring that my imports are now resolved to the local 1.1 version, now I can use `(decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())`, but I still have the same problem: the callback isn't intercepted, and I just end with the unprocessed 302 redirect data instead of the result I'm expecting.

Comment: You'll need to have the correct URL defined in your project in the [Google APIs Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) and you need to take the `/oauth2callback` route out of your app. As for the `302`, that is expected and is the point of the callback.

Comment: here is [a screenshot of my API conf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/368761/bugreport/google-api-cliend-id-configuration.png). But I don't understand what you mean by *"302 is expected & the point of callback"*. My understanding is that `appengine.py` should intercept it, and return to the original caller the answer to my query: in the above code, I call `youtube_create_playlist()`, but instead of getting the new playlist ID string, I get a 302 string: [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/368761/bugreport/playlist-id-returns-302-string.png). What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `appengine.py` is no longer used. Your decorator is intercepting it. Based on that screenshot, the `302` is definitely intended. It is the auth page where you need to accept the OAuth 2.0 dialog.

Comment: I tried to remove the `/oauth2callback` route out of my `app.yaml`, and I also tried to add `{- /oauth2callback\n script: myapp.update}`, but in both cases, instead of the 302 string I now get `None`. Can you be more specific to what's wrong in my configuration and how I can fix it? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the `yaml`. I did that, which let me narrow down on the issue, which was that the `get(self)` method of my `UpdatePage(webapp2.RequestHandler)` class wasn't decorated. I thought it was preferable to decorate the finer-grained function and leave `get` undecorated (because on its own it does *not* do anything requiring oauth, it just *calls* functions requiring oauth). After moving the decorator up to the `get` method (and removing it from the lower-level oauth-using methods), it works! A bajillion thanks for the help :)